# Convert XML to AAF

Tags: pro-tools, aaf

Is there any way to convert a XML file from FCPX to an AAF for use in Pro Tools without X2Pro?

Seeing if there is a way to do this other than buying X2Pro.

Answer (score 0):

All the forums for audio on FCPX state the same thing: you need X2 or X2Pro.

X2 looks like being the cheaper option, and it seems like it does carry out the conversion, but all the other tools that used to do this no longer exist.

Answer (score -2):

once exported your XML from fcx open it in logic x and from there export aaf.